# HAproxy lua support: want to call core.action method from Lua file

Tags: lua, load-balancing, haproxy

I am new to haproxy integration
I want to call an action for every http request

test_world.lua file code

```
core.register_action("test_world", { "tcp-req", "http-req" },function(txn)
  txn:Info("Hello world")
end)
```

haproxy.cfg file code

```
global
 lua-load /usr/local/etc/haproxy/test_world.lua


defaults
  mode http

frontend  http
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  mode http
  http-request  lua.test_world
```

I am making request from browser and telnet as well, but not getting the response

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong "hello world" example.
In your example you are registering a Lua function as an [action](https://www.arpalert.org/src/haproxy-lua-api/1.7/index.html#core.register_action).
Functions registered as actions are more commonly used to manipulate http-requests and not to send http responses.

If you need to send a response instead of the backend server, you need to use an [applet](https://www.arpalert.org/src/haproxy-lua-api/1.7/index.html#AppletHTTP), like shown in the following example:

```
core.register_service("hello-world", "http", function(applet)
 local response = "Hello World !"
 applet:set_status(200)
 applet:add_header("content-length", string.len(response))
 applet:add_header("content-type", "text/plain")
 applet:start_response()
 applet:send(response)
end)
```

Comment: yes I want to manipulate the request and pass on to backend server, just to show message I was printing it.

Comment: If you want to show a message as a reply instead of the real servers, you have to use the applet there no other way around it.

Comment: @Mo3m3n If I want to modify stick table counter using api will it be possible with register_action ? I suppose I have to connect to unix socket and then send a command ? But is there a alternative ?